# Laravel new user registration, activation with email and secure login

Tags: laravel

I am working on a **Laravel 4.2** project.

I already have implemented an email activation module for new user registration. Whenever a new user registers, I provide an `activation link` to him `in an email` and `clicking` on `link`, I `compare` the `token (a random string with 30 characters)` I have provided with `link` and user's `email` address `with database records`. If found to be matching, I just set `is_active` field of users table to `true` and `redirect` him to `login page` with a Congratulations message for successful activation.

But now, I **DON'T** want him to `redirect` to `login` page, but if successful activation, I want him `logged in directly` to his account.

But I believe that authenticate an user with just a string token and email address is not a secure way.

There must be something that I can trust on. Many sites do this including stackoverflow itself but I am not sure how?

Can you please guide me how to do this?

Comment: As long as the token has expired and cannot be used again, I don't see why the method you suggested wouldn't be secure

Comment: @ChrisTownsend I've used Auth::login($user) method and it seems working OK for now. But still I would require some expert's review whether am I going on right direction or not?

Comment: Well okay firstly think about how they get entry to that function.. It is from a link with a token in. Could that token be guessed or brute forced? Could you throttle it so that wouldn't be possible. Do you instantly reject anyone without a correct token? Are you using eloquent for the token to ensure no sql injection?

Comment: Could you show me an example of your token please